# Dexie.js on Electron eats up huge storage amounts when updating record inside a loop

Tags: electron, indexeddb, dexie

I have an Electron app where an user can upload a file. I extract some information from this file and store this data on IndexedDB using Dexie.

Here's the Dexie.js setup:

```js
import Dexie from "dexie";

const db = new Dexie("raw");

db.version(1).stores({
  files:
    "++id, name, path, status, total, remainingUsers, progress, scores, cap, userColumn, leadingAt, limit, calls",
});

export default db;
```

I add records extracted from the file to this `files` record:

```js
await db.files.add({
  name: file.name,
  path: file.path,
  status: progress === total ? "done" : "pending",
  progress,
  cap: datasetCap || Number.parseFloat(cap),
  remainingUsers,
  total,
  scores,
  userColumn,
  leadingAt,
  limit: Number.parseInt(limit),
});
```

In another screen the user can start a process that calls an API, and with the result of this API I update the record in the IndexedDB. This process is made inside a loop, and I call Dexie again to update the record:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < file.remainingUsers.length; i++) {
  if (!_processing.current || calls >= file.limit) break;

  const currentUser = file.remainingUsers[i];

  const result = // calls an API
  progress += 1;
  calls += 1;
  const score = parseScore(result);
  scores[currentUser] = score;

  if (_processing.current) {
    setIndicators({ progress, calls });
  }

  // Updating the record
  await db.files.update(file.id, {
    scores,
    progress,
    remainingUsers: file.remainingUsers.slice(i + 1),
  });
}
```

The application is working very well. But my tester noticed that his Mac was out of storage space while running the application (while in the screen that does the loop and updates the record).

By investigating a little bit, I found out that when I update a record on IndexedDB, the user directory of my app increases at least 20Mb in space. In a thousand records processed, this consumes a ton of space!

Am I doing something wrong here? How could I fix this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: maybe https://dexie.org/docs/Table/Table.bulkPut() helps?

Comment: Hmm, maybe. I will try implementing with put() and bulkPut() today and return to you.